# TOP Clause in SQL in Where Caluse

Tags: sql-server

I want to use top clause in where Condition.

I want to do like this:-

```
SELECT column_name_1,column_name_2,column_name_n 
FROM   table_name 
Where  condition and top n.
```

Comment: What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: I want to get same data as in. SELECT TOP 2 column_name,column_name From table_name. But i want to use top clause in where condition

Comment: TOP n is defined just after the SELECT keyword. Place it there, not after where clause.

Comment: i got your point but i need some query that exactly work as that

Comment: any example? provide more inputs and outputs

Comment: You are probably going in wrong direction provide example

Comment: Do a row_number() and write where rn >= 2

Comment: Is this "Some system only allows me to specify a `where` clause and constructs the rest of the query automatically. How do I limit the number of results?" If so (or similar restrictions), please *specifically* describe them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a ranking function ([`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)/[`RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)/[`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) depending on your requirements) and a subquery. But I have no idea why you would *want* to do this. It is more verbose and has no benefits that I can see - consider the following queries, which are equivalent (in terms of results, not necessarily execution plans):

```
DECLARE @N INT = 5;

SELECT TOP (@N) name
FROM sys.all_objects
ORDER BY object_id;

SELECT name
FROM (  SELECT object_id, name, RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id)
        FROM sys.all_objects
    ) AS o
WHERE RowNum <= @N;
```

I know which one I find easier to read